# Trouble with inputting data from a file

Tags: java, sorting, file-io

I'm trying to input data from a file that's in the form of

```
1000
16   11
221   25
234   112
348   102
451   456
183   218
78   338
365   29
114   393
441   369
531   460
...
```

I'm having trouble because I keep getting IndexOutOfBounds exceptions or NoSuchElement exceptions. How do I put the data into an array so that I can easily sort it later?

```js
public class shortestRoute 
{   
 
    public static void printGrid(int[][] adjMat)
    {
       for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
       {
          for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
          {
          System.out.printf("%5d", adjMat[i][j]);
          }
          System.out.println();
       }
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        File file = new File("rtest1-2.dat");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        
        
     scanner.useDelimiter("\\s+");
     
     int N = scanner.nextInt();
     int[][] adjMat = new int[N][2];

     for(int i=0; i < N; i++)
         for (int j=0; j < 2; j++) 
              adjMat[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
        
        printGrid(adjMat);

    }

}
```

Comment: So which one are you getting - `IndexOutOfBoundsException` or `NoSuchElementException`? Bonus question: where are you getting them?

Comment: With the code above I'm getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. For some reason it's not inputting the array correctly. It's only inputting 40 data points or so before it hits an exception.

Comment: Code snippets are for JS, not Java. Stop adding them. Click the "Run code snippet" and see for yourself that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 int N = scanner.nextInt();
```

This will pick up N as 1000. 
But in the given as example you got only 22 integers and  the NoSuchElement errors comes right after 22nd element.

if you provide enough input, then you can get rid of this error. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You're iterating to much. You have 1000 lines with 2 `Integer` but you are iterating over 1000x1000 `Integer`.
Just switch the inner for loop to a max of 2:

```
for(int i=0; i < N; i++){
  for (int j=0; j < 2; j++) {
    adjMat[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
  }
}
```

and you should also lower the allocation of your array:

```
int[][] adjMat = new int[N][2];
```